# OpenSSH says 'Permission denied' or 'Connection reset' after I modify my user name through netplwiz on my Windows server

Tags: windows-10, ssh, windows-11, openssh, windows-server

The orginal user name of my Windows PC was the first five letters of my email that I used to register my Microsoft account. It looks quite weird, so I modified it through netplwiz.
I've installed `OpenSSH SSH Server` (i.e. `sshd`) on my Windows PC and enabled the `sshd` service so that the computer can work as a Windows server.
I tried to login into my Windows server in the following ways. And the related errors are listed as follows.

```
> whoami
MachineName\NewUserName

> ssh NewUserName@127.0.0.1
NewUserName@127.0.0.1's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

> ssh MachineName\NewUserName@127.0.0.1
Connection reset by 127.0.0.1 port 22

> ssh OriginalUserName@127.0.0.1
OriginalUserName@127.0.0.1's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

> ssh MachineName\OriginalUserName@127.0.0.1
OriginalUserName@127.0.0.1's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

If I change my user name back to the original one, then I can login successfully through the following commands.

```
> whoami
MachineName\OriginalUserName

> ssh OriginalUserName@127.0.0.1
(login successfully)

> ssh MachineName\OriginalUserName@127.0.0.1
(login successfully)
```

Besides, I created a new local account `test`, which also works well.

```
> whoami
MachineName\test

> ssh test@127.0.0.1
(login successfully)

> ssh MachineName\test@127.0.0.1
(login successfully)
```

Some more information about my Windows PC:

```
OS: Windows 11
OpenSSH SSH Server: OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
```

It can be inferred that the problem is caused by the user name.
**These are my questions:

1.How does ssh check whether a user name exists?

2.Is there a way to login with my new user name?**

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that my problem is that my new *user name* is the same as my *user domain* (i.e. `%USERNAME% == %USERDOMAIN%`). Everything has been working well since I changed my user name into one *different* from my user domain.

These are the answers to my questions:

1. The command `net user` outputs a list with all the available user
   names under one's user domain. The related information is also
   contained in `control panel`, `netplwiz`, `lusrmgr.msc`, etc.
2. One can login with a new user name successfully as long as the new
   user name differs from the user domain. The environment variable
   `%USERNAME%` refers to one's user name, and `%USERDOMAIN%` refers
   to one's user domain.

Comment: Welcome to SU, and excellent you got your issue solved. However this is a little bit unclear, "user domain"? Do you mean that your new local username is the same as your domain username? Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1770281/edit) the answer to clarify it.

Comment: Thanks! I've clarified it in my answer above. If there still exist some problems or ambiguities, feel free to point them out.